# Apparmor default allow profile

Tags: apparmor

I read this page and confused: http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/FAQ#What_is_Default_Deny_.28White_listing.29

I want to create a profile for my command and I want my profile be in **"default allow (black listing)"** mode. I used aa-genprof command to create the profile and it is created in **default deny** mode.

How can I change it to default allow?